# Creating a Facebook post with rich/interactive content

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm looking for a way to create a Wall Post from an Android app that can contain styled/interactive content. Something similar to what the Nike+ Running App does:

[image]

What is the correct approach to achieve this? My app generates a "score" for the user that he can share on Facebook. Currently, I'm publishing to "me/feed" but as far as I can see this only allows plain text elements (message, caption, description). I am using Facebook Android SDK 3.0.

Any ideas/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special type of Open Graph data: "[Bike, Walk, Run](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/fitness/)"

You have to configure your app to use those actions in the **Open Graph** panel of your Developer area:

[image]

Also notice that the app must be in the "**Health and Fitness**" category.

For info:

- [Open Graph documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)
- [Facebook App Developer panel](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)